# How old is the oldest intact DNA?

Tags: dna

DNA fragments are known from bone fragments from the Mesozoic, but these don't count. I'm guessing the oldest DNA is recovered from permafrost, but how old exactly?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but I'm not sure why your example doesn't count. Can you expand on that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, the ***oldest intact DNA*** found is actually [**419 million** years old](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1472-4669.2009.00218.x/abstract), and it belongs to (not surprisingly) bacteria. Samples were extracted from surface-sterilized salt of different geological ages (23, 121, 419 million years of age, MYA).

But as you mentioned, these are fragments. Studies on the [half-life of DNA](http://www.nature.com/news/dna-has-a-521-year-half-life-1.11555) suggest that even under ideal circumstances, DNA sequences older than 1.5 million years will be too short to be readable.

The **oldest genome** known to date, though, is [**700,000** years old](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nature12323.html), and was recovered from samples from a horse leg bone. You were correct, the leg was in **permafrost**. That's a considerable jump from mastodon and polar bear fossils which were about 50,000 and 110,000 years old.